# Setting System.Text.Json's PropertyNamingPolicy per web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I'm upgrading our codebase from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json. One of the tricky requirements we have is that we need to set the casing in our Web Api to pascal case or camel case based on the web request, as our legacy ASP.NET website is coded to use pascal case and our new Angular website is coded to use camel case.

The legacy website sends an "Accept" request header value of "application/json;case=default", and then we have a JSON Formatter registered that handles changing the casing based on this.

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonDefaultCaseFormatter : NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter
{
    public NewtonsoftJsonDefaultCaseFormatter(List<JsonConverter> converters) : base(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(), NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include }, ArrayPool<char>.Shared, new MvcOptions(), new MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions())
    {
        foreach (var converter in converters)
            SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
        SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;case=default"));
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how we can achieve the same behavior with System.Text.Json? On Startup I'm setting the default behavior to camel case, but now I need a way to change the option for the requests that have the specific Accept request header.

```
var mvcBuilder = services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => GetDefaultJsonOptions());

public static JsonSerializerOptions GetDefaultJsonOptions()
{
    var defaultOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    defaultOptions.Converters.Add(new ConcurrentBagConverterFactory());
    defaultOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
    defaultOptions.Converters.Add(DictionaryJsonConverterFactory.Default);
    defaultOptions.Converters.Add(new SqlGeographyConverter());
    defaultOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    defaultOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    defaultOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    defaultOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    return defaultOptions;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Register an additional and custom [`SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.systemtextjsonoutputformatter)  that outputs that other/legacy json format.

This custom formatter must only handle the `application/json;case=default` accept http header and have its own `JsonSerializerOptions` - see the constructor below, using PascalCase.

```
public class LegacyJsonOutputFormatter : SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter
{
    public LegacyJsonOutputFormatter()
        : base(new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            // Configure any settings.
            // PropertyNamingPolicy = ...
        })
    { }

    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        var accept = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Accept.ToString();
        return accept.Equals("application/json;case=default", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Register this custom formatter as shown below.

Also note the correction in how to configure the default `JsonSerializerOptions`, since that lambda is an `Action` instead of a `Func`.

```
var mvcBuilder = services
    .AddControllers(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(new LegacyJsonOutputFormatter()))        
    .AddJsonOptions(options => SetDefaultJsonOptions(options.JsonSerializerOptions));

public static void SetDefaultJsonOptions(JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    options.Converters.Add(new ConcurrentBagConverterFactory());
    options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
    options.Converters.Add(DictionaryJsonConverterFactory.Default);
    options.Converters.Add(new SqlGeographyConverter());
    options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    options.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    
}
```

Now result content of type `application/json` will be handled by the default/regular json formatter using the settings from `SetDefaultJsonOptions`, whereas `application/json;case=default` will be handled by the custom formatter.